VS Code C# Dev Kit Errors on Spawn .Net Server
I have had a working .Net MAUI app for a month.  Everything was fine and I've used the iOS simulators and published several versions to TestFlight (just highlighting that its been working).
One day I could no longer debug as the folder would open, but it seems the solution was no longer identified.  I was looking at the OUTPUT logs for C# Dev Kit and tried to click the "Create .Net Project" and saw that the logs got an error spawning a .Net server.
Also - I use a MacInCloud managed server.
I've reinstalled C# Dev Kit & .NET MAUI extensions.  I have also tried their pre-release versions.  No help.  The full C# Dev Kit error is below.  BTW - I am logged in to use C# Dev Kit.  The error references a failure getting entitlements, so I tried logging out and logging in again.
The below output occurs when I click "Create .Net Project".  I suspect its also what occurs when I try to open my existing projects as I normally do.
I am using .Net 8 and MAUI.  I know that Visual Studio retired.  But I have been using VS COde for a month, so not sure why this would be related.

Starting Spawn .NET server...
Using preinstalled .NET runtime at "/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet" to load Dev Kit processes.
Found installed dotnet location "/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet" to load projects.
.NET server STDERR: Unhandled exception.
.NET server STDERR: System.IO.IOException: The system cannot open the device or file specified. : '-321239078-ServiceHubControllerSingleInstanceMutex'
at System.Threading.Mutex.CreateMutexCore(Boolean initiallyOwned, String name, Boolean& createdNew)
at System.Threading.Mutex..ctor(Boolean initiallyOwned, String name)
at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.Controller.MainAsync(String pipeName, String[] args, String serializedTelemetrySession, Nullable`1 controllerCooldownTimeout)
at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.Program.Main(String[] args)
IdeBenefitsSource: Failed to fetch entitlements. Error: 'Error: Request to https://api.subscriptions.visualstudio.microsoft.com/Me/Entitlements/IDEBenefits?api-version=2023-03-26&caller=vscode failed with status code: 401 and response ""'
.NET server STDERR: Unhandled exception.
.NET server STDERR: Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.ControllerConnectionException: Controller terminated before accepting connections. Exit code: 134.
at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubControllerClient.StartAsync(ServiceHubConfig config, String clientName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.LaunchOrFindControllerAsync()
at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.GetLocationServiceAsync()
at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.Shared.ServiceHubRetry.ExecuteAsync[TReturnType](Func1 actionToExecute, TraceSource logger, ServiceHubRetryConfiguration1 serviceHubRetryConfiguration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.Shared.ServiceHubRetry.ExecuteAsync[TReturnType](Func1 actionToExecute, TraceSource logger, ServiceHubRetryConfiguration1 serviceHubRetryConfiguration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.GetThisAsRemoteServiceBrokerAsync()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Server.ServiceBroker.Program.RunAsync(Stream rpcStream, String bridgePipeName, ExportProvider exportProvider, Boolean includeServiceHub, String serviceHubConfigPath, Func2 traceSourceFactory, TraceSource traceSource, TelemetrySession telemetrySession, TelemetryEvent perfTelemetryEvent, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Server.ServiceBroker.Program.RunAsync(Stream rpcStream, String bridgePipeName, ExportProvider exportProvider, Boolean includeServiceHub, String serviceHubConfigPath, Func2 traceSourceFactory, TraceSource traceSource, TelemetrySession telemetrySession, TelemetryEvent perfTelemetryEvent, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Server.ServiceBroker.Program.<>c.<b__7_1>d.MoveNext()
End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.CommandLine.Invocation.AnonymousCommandHandler.InvokeAsync(InvocationContext context)
at System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationPipeline.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<b__19_0>d.MoveNext()
End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<b__6_0>d.MoveNext()
End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<b__1_0>d.MoveNext()
End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationPipeline.InvokeAsync(IConsole console)
at System.CommandLine.Parsing.ParseResultExtensions.InvokeAsync(ParseResult parseResult, IConsole console)
at System.CommandLine.Parsing.ParserExtensions.InvokeAsync(Parser parser, String[] args, IConsole console)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Server.ServiceBroker.Program.Main(String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Server.ServiceBroker.Program.(String[] args)
.NET server STDERR: [createdump] Invalid process id: task_for_pid(98151) FAILED (os/kern) failure (5)
[createdump] This failure may be because createdump or the application is not properly signed and entitled.
.NET server STDERR: [createdump] Failure took 0ms
.NET server STDOUT: [createdump] Target process is alive
Error occurred in launchDotNetServer: Error: Stream terminated before required bytes were read.
Failed at 'Spawn .NET server' (1194ms) with error: Error: Stream terminated before required bytes were read.
.NET server exited with null

And here is the error I get trying to open a solution
Starting Open a solution...
Starting handling solution file "/Users/user263333/Documents/Waldo/Waldo.sln" in Dev Kit server...
Starting Clear environment...
Failed at 'Clear environment' (0ms) with error: Error: Stream terminated before required bytes were read.
Failed at 'handling solution file "/Users/user263333/Documents/Waldo/Waldo.sln" in Dev Kit server' (0ms) with error: Error: Stream terminated before required bytes were read.
Failed at 'Open a solution' (1ms) with error: SolutionOpenError: Run into errors while opening the solution: Error: Stream terminated before required bytes were read.

Have you tried a new clean build? The error mentions a mutex -321239078-ServiceHubControllerSingleInstanceMutex. Ensure that no other processes are holding this mutex and causing a conflict.
